# MySQL insert multiple variables from a json type in a trigger

Tags: mysql, json

I use `MySQL 5.7.9` so it supports internal JSON type. I create an 'after insert' trigger to insert relative data from A table to B table, this relative data is a JSON format data in table A.
 I can parse and insert this data into B separately in a while loop. 
My question is how can I do this insert event using an insert statement like insert into values (x,x),(y,y)... for it's high-efficiency.

```
 set @jsonO := CAST(NEW.targets AS JSON);
 set @targetLen := JSON_LENGTH(@jsonO);
 set valueStr = NULL;
 set target = 0;
 while target < @targetLen do
   set valueStr = CONCAT_WS(',',valueStr,CONCAT('(',JSON_EXTRACT(NEW.targets,CONCAT('$[',target,']')) ,NEW.id,')'));
   #insert into user_info(userid,infoid) values(JSON_EXTRACT(NEW.targets,CONCAT('$[',target,']')),NEW.id);
   #!!! INSERT INTO SINGLE ROW IS OK BUT IS INEFFICIENCY
   set target = target + 1;
 end while;
 insert into user_info(userid,infoid) values ???;
```

My question is how to insert multiple rows at once using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [example in W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp) you can use the same example for your own

Comment: Thanks. I think MySQLLi is connector library between PHP and mysql.  I want to know how to implement this just in trigger,not use any language like PHP,Java,Ruby or others. Actually, I want to know if there is a way using variable to replace the WHOLE 'values' part in insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but what about using prepared statement ?

Build up the query string in the loop (prepare phase), and execute after the loop.

I have not tried yet !

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-prepared-statements.html